# dump "git log --notes" to shell pipe?

Tags: git, bash, pipeline

I can't seem to get `git log` to produce notes for machine-consumption.

`git log` will open `less` as a pager and notes are shown.

`git --no-pager log [--notes|--show-notes]` wont show notes.

`git --no-pager log --notes | less` will show notes.

`git --no-pager log --notes | less | cat` wont.

`git log --notes > gitlog.txt` works, but I'm trying to avoid managing files.

`cat <(git log --notes)` won't show but is using a temporary file

`less -f <(git log --notes --oneline)` will show.

`git log 1>&2 | cat 2>&1 | cat` just opens less still.

`git log 2>&1 | cat` doesn't work

`git log 2>&1 | cat 1>&2 | cat` doesn't work

---

Help I'm so confused, what black magic is causing part of the data I want to just be dropped but apparently only at display time?

P.S. if your upset with all the useless-use-of-cats, imagine a perl/sed/grep/awk filter, ultimately I'm trying to strip some newlines so the note's value appends the lines of the `git log --oneline` format.

Comment: Have you considered separate `git notes` lookups?

Comment: weird, this command works for me: `git --no-pager log --notes`. also, i believe the `--notes` is there by default, how about the command `git --no-pager log`, does it work? if not, how about `GIT_PAGER=cat git log --notes`

Comment: BTW, `cat <(git log --notes)` **does not** actually create a tempfile. On any modern OS it'll evaluate to something like `/dev/fd/12`, which is just a reference to a file descriptor table entry -- nothing hits disk to create it.

Answer (score 1):

With git 2.12.2, I'm entirely unable to reproduce the behavior (re: notes not being printed) described in the question.

---

That said, the following performs the requested operation and **does not** create a temporary file (on any system where bash could detect `/dev/fd` or `/proc/self/fd` support at compile time), and generates one-line output with notes appended to each line having them:

```
#!/bin/bash

in_note=0
notes=
last_line=

while IFS= read -r line; do
  if (( in_note == 0 )) && [[ $line = "Notes:" ]]; then  ## at the start of a note
    in_note=1; continue
  fi
  if (( in_note == 0 )); then                            ## outside any note
    [[ $last_line ]] && printf '%s\n' "$last_line"
    last_line=$line
    continue
  fi
  if [[ $line = "" ]]; then                              ## at the end of a note
    in_note=0
    printf '%s|%s\n' "$last_line" "$notes"
    last_line=
    continue
  fi
  # all notes are prefixed by four spaces, so the below doesn't need extra spacing
  notes+="$line"                                         ## inside of a note
done < <(git log --oneline --notes)
[[ $last_line ]] && printf '%s\n' "$last_line"
```